trying to finagle concise searchbox & menu
I'm trying to setup the ugliest/simplest/most functional searchbox and multitier menu on a static webpage.
Maybe something like this or this but without all the theming and fancyness to just send queries to different search engines and sites around the web. Do you really need all these lines of JS and CSS? Think ~100 of the mycroft search plugins in a single multitier search dropdown next to a searchbox form field.
I'm probably searching for examples in the wrong places because everything I find is flashy and 50+ lines of code. As a related/secondary question, where are the best places to find only concise code snippets?
enter search terms BOX (sorry my diagram keeps getting eaten by stackoverflow)
search engine > DDG
google
maps > gmaps
waze
openstreetmaps
calculators > wolframalpha
you hopefully get the idea....
I got as far as this only to realize definitely not what I want...


            <form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
            <select name="sengines">
            <option value="https://duckduckgo.com/?hps=1&q=" selected>DDG</option>
            <option value="http://www.google.com/search?q=" selected>Google</option>
            <option value="http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=">Yahoo!</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="searchterms">
            <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
            </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function dosearch() {
var sf=document.searchform;
var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
window.location.href = submitto;
return false;
}
</script> 


